# AccessViolationException while trying to P/Invoke a simple C++ function

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, stdcall

I am trying to call the a function in a C++ exe from my C# program. This is dllmain.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#define EXPORT(type) extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) type __stdcall

EXPORT(void) SetupEngine(HWND handle)
{
    printf("asd\n");
}
```

And this is the P/Invoke declaration and the call:

```
[DllImport("program.exe", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern void SetupEngine(IntPtr hWnd);
// ...
SetupEngine(IntPtr.Zero);
```

For some reason, this call results in the following exception:
`System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'`

If I change the function to just simply return an integer then it seems to work, and the C# program receives the int value (which shows that the exported name isn't mangled). But if I put basically any other code in there (including a simple printf) then I get the exception.

Both project's architectures are the same (x86), the .NET version is 4.8 and the c++ platform toolset version is v142 with Windows SDK 10.0.

Am I missing something obvious here?

**EDIT**

I created a simple [VS2019 solution](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yBddlZu9q9priFDtzBQn7wciG22ezD14) that reproduces the crash.

Comment: Does your C# program have a console?

Comment: I just created one with `AllocConsole()`, but it still crashes. And not only with printf, but with basically any code. For example, originally the first function call in `SetupEngie` was a `srand()` which gave the same result.

Comment: If it's so simple, why don't you provide a reproducing project so we can have a real look.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have edited the question and included the projects.

Comment: Import from a .dll. not an .exe: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ff7b79d-ff75-4526-a876-ca83170a3f8f/exporting-functions-from-exe?forum=vclanguage